# Checking if a textbox is "0" or null or empty

Tags: c#

Im trying to see if a textbox is `"0"` or empty using the following code.

I hoped I could use the `!` operator on `IsNulorEmpty` but seems it doesn't do what I want. Is there an easy way to do this on one line?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextbox.Text) || MyTextbox.Text != "0")
{ 
    //string is either null, empty or 0
}
else
{ 
    //string has a value
}
```

Comment: Remove the first `!` and change `!=` to `==`. Look at your condition compared with your comment...

Comment: Simply put, your logic is completely backwards from your requirements.

Answer (score 12):

The code is doing what you write, but you are confused about operator evaluations:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextbox.Text) || MyTextbox.Text == "0")
{ 
     //string is either null, empty or 0
}
else
{ 
     //string has a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextbox.Text) || MyTextbox.Text == "0"))
{ 
   //string has a value
}
else
{ 
   //string is either null, empty or 0
}
```

Comment: Your code has the same issue as the OP. You have the conditionals reversed. Look at your code vs. the comments in the blocks.

Comment: @JustinNiessner It's not the exact same issue.  It's actually just the opposite of what the OP wants, so swapping the code in the `if` and `else` would work here.

Comment: @JustinNiessner is correct, all that you've done is add an extra parenthesis around the if statement, it doesn't change the fact that the logic in that statement is the exact opposite of what the comments state